# Problema em execução SQL

Tags: sql

Boa tarde.

Eu tenho uma query simples em SQL

```
Select * from Tabela Order By Campo
```

Onde esse campo ele é string, e essa string possui dados como `"xyz001"`, `"xyz002"`, `"xyz0011"`, dessa forma, o `"xyz0011"` é exibido primeiro que o `"xyz002"`, como solucionar isso?

Comment: Você quer ordenar conforme outra lista, seria isso?

Comment: Solucionar o que? Está correto. Os primeiros 5 caracteres são iguais, o 5o. é diferente um deles é "1", o outro é "2", o 2 vem depois do 1, é normal. Se queria que fosse numérico deveria usar número ou então manter a quantidade de dígitos iguais. Se um deles fosse " xyz0002" ficaria certo.

Comment: Sim, a ordenação está correta porque está a tratar com alfanuméricos. Se a coluna `Campo` tiver sempre esse formato, consegue resolver isso. Tem?

Comment: Ela sempre vai ter esse formato. Na verdade ela está mais para xyz1,,, xyz11

Comment: @Maniero a solução mais fácil pra mim foi igualar os campos mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Se a coluna `Campo` tiver sempre o mesmo formato (caracteres alfanuméricos + numéricos posteriores) então pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT      Campo
FROM        Tabela
ORDER BY    CAST(SUBSTRING(Campo, 4, LEN(Campo)) AS INT)
```

Nesse exemplo utilizei o formato que indicou na questão (3 caracteres alfanuméricos), mas pode sempre ser adaptado para outros cenários.

Se não tiver sempre o mesmo formato, então teria de arranjar uma forma de separar os alfa dos numéricos e ordenar da mesma forma.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas preferi igualar a quantidade de campos no select mesmo

Answer (score 1):

Bom se você utiliza Oracle eu vejo pelo menos duas alternativas para sua questão. Você usar Expressão Regular e outra solução seria utilizar a função "substr" para buscar os números e depois ordena-los. Segue um exemplo aí.

```
    CREATE TABLE tab_notas(identificador VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL) -- Tabela exemplo

        -- Registros de exemplo
        BEGIN
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('XYNDY00001');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('ZYNDY00011');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('XYXDY00104');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('VYNDY00206');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('PYNDY00020');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('MYODY02301');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('HYNDZ00701');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('KINDY00801');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('NYNDY00301');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('KYNDY00111');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('BYMDP00211');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('PYNDY00806');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('TYNDE00653');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('AINDY00207');
          INSERT INTO tab_notas(identificador) VALUES('RYNDM00511');
        END;

-- 1: Primeira Solução
select regexp_replace(n.identificador, '[^0-9]') identificador_numero_1,
       to_number(regexp_replace(n.identificador, '[^0-9]')) identificador_numero_2,
       n.identificador
  from tab_notas n
 order by to_number(regexp_replace(n.identificador, '[^0-9]'));

-- 2: Segunda Solução
select substr(n.identificador, 6, 5) identificador_numero_1,
       to_number(substr(n.identificador, 6, 5)) identificador_numero_2,
       n.identificador
  from tab_notas n
 order by to_number(substr(n.identificador, 6, 5));
```